# How do I get Ruby 'puts' to write data into a file?

Tags: ruby

I have the following code that I want to use to ping IP addresses and write to a file. It all works fine, except I can't get it to write to the file.

```
server = %w'192.168.150.254
192.168.150.251
192.168.120.1
192.168.120.2'

File.open('/test/test2.out','w') do |s|
  server.each do |p|
    r = `ping -a -n 1 #{p}`
    puts r
  end
end
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Change `puts r` to `s.puts r`. You're writing to stdout instead of to `s`. (See [`Kernel#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#method-i-puts) and [`IO#puts`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/IO.html#method-i-puts))